# Why JavaScript doesn't work with this var name?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
reinaldo_init = {name: "reinaldo", age:22};
Agregar metodos a los objetos
*/
function people(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.retirement = yearsLeft; //NO LLEVA PARENTESIS AL RELACIONAR LA FUNCION
}
function yearsLeft(){
    var numYears = 65 - this.age;
    return numYears;
}
var reinaldo = new people("reinaldo acosta", 22);
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Calling code
document.write(reinaldo.retirement());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ok, right after the body tag I try to print the retirement of reinaldo, THE ISSUE IS, I type reinaldo.retirement() and it doesn't provide anything... yet if I change it to bucky, it actually returns the retirement years... can someone tell me why doesn't JavaScript accept my name, or why doesn't it work when I use my name (reinaldo)?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
reinaldo_init = {name: "reinaldo", age:22};
Agregar metodos a los objetos
*/
function people(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.retirement = yearsLeft; //NO LLEVA PARENTESIS AL RELACIONAR LA FUNCION
}
function yearsLeft(){
    var numYears = 65 - this.age;
    return numYears;
}
var reinaldo = new people("reinaldo acosta", 22);
</script>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Calling code
document.write(reinaldo.retirement());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: Actually they assign the function `yearsLeft()` to `retirement`

Comment: I have tested here and it does returns `43`, with the parentheses `()`, IF I take out the parentheses `()` it returns: `function yearsLeft(){ var numYears = 65 - this.age; return numYears; }`. Post a code snippet to see if it runs normal here in SO.

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome

Comment: @Matt Burland: missed that, you're correct! Thanks

Comment: This is the issue, try running the exact code, just as is, without the () it returns undefined, with the () it returns the retirement age, ONLY if the object is different than reinaldo, I changed var reinaldo to var something_else and it worked just fine, the issue here is, JavaScript for some reason is crashing when it reads my name as a variable... why?, I tried with other several names but it just doesn't accept mine

Comment: @Detallado, did you copy-paste that `reinaldo` token from somewhere, or did you type it by hand?

Comment: Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/awng43z3/

Comment: Ricky S, does it work for you with "reinaldo" as the object name?

Comment: I copied your code exactly.  Works fine.

Comment: It works perfectly for me in Chrome. I copied your code line by line into a text editor and opened it up as a static HTML page. It shows `43` as the output. No problems whatsoever.

Comment: your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/pafg25dj/ (only modified mehod to display the call to conform with jsfiddle)

Comment: Works fine in Firefox. Add the line `console.debug("this=", this);` inside `yearsLeft` and you can see it's running in the appropriate context.

Comment: Well, I tried in all browsers, with proxies, and all of them return error, they simply do not show anything with reinaldo as an object name, but it does show the result as any other name, I tried yax, x, a, c, b, variable, random_name, among others, and all of them showed the result and worked, except reinaldo...

Comment: @Detallado are you using some libraries? Or could something else modify reinaldo?

Comment: Well.. thank you maraca, I was a total idiot, yes, I had loaded into my HTML head an external js library I made a while back... thank you so much, sorry for being so stupid...

Comment: My fiddle isn't loading for some reason.  There were two others that posted a fiddle, try those.

Comment: can you put it online so that we can actually navigate in your code.. to se if it works?

Comment: @Detallado you are welcome, it happens to us all, not seeing the forest because of all the trees... as the Germans say.

Comment: CaldasGSM, the code the exactly the same as the one I posted originally, I just had to comment this line
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/javascript_lib_p.js"></script>-->
because I had a bunch of trash code in that lib and I had one named just like me

This is a bad coding practice I have, I name variable things only I will understand